# Is it Possible to Pull All the iframe tags from a webpage

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I don't know whether it is possible or not. There is a webpage that Has so many `<iframe>` tags (youtube, facebook etc video embeds) like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=483633655049394"
width="680" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe width="680" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XpEnFZGkK8A
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I want to do the following

I give the URL of the Webpage and It resturns me all the `<iframe> ... </iframe>` tags.

How Can I do that in php.

Comment: `$document->getElementsByTagName("iframe")` should do it.

Comment: On Stackoverflow it does not make any sense to ask if something is possible. In programmig, most often it is. So the answer to your question is Yes. And you do that in PHP by programming it. Use a XML/HTML parser for that. [Parsing and processing HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456)

Answer (score 2):

No xpath is required here. You can use `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName('iframe');`. Check the comment of @Bamar below the question (thx). I expect using DOM without xpath being faster.

However I'll keep the original xpath answer for reference.

---

*Original answer*

Use the following xpath query:

```
//iframe
```

it will select all the `<iframe>` tags in document regardless of their position in the document tree.

Example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourhtml);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//iframe') as $iframe) {
    echo $iframe->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to get only the `src` value. I want the full data of `<iframe> ... </iframe>`

Comment: Then I would suggest that you read a basic DOM php tutorial. You need at least a little understanding of what you are doing